# react-native AsyncStorage.getItem takes long time to get data, sometimes no response at all

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

`AsyncStorage.getItem` takes long time to get data, sometimes no response at all. I do understand that `getItem` is `async` function. But the amount of waiting time is not acceptable and not reasonable.

Anyone facing such issue? any workaround?

the `react-native` version is `0.55.4`

Comment: It will take some time but not much. Can you reproduce the issue here [snack](http://snack.expo.io)?

Comment: Does that happen in both platforms?

Comment: @PritishVaidya you can try with a simple app, grab the example from https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html and run it.

Comment: @TareqEl-Masri currently the app I develop only for android, I have no idea about IOS.

Comment: Tell us more, are you testing on real device or emulator? How long does it take? Is that time consistent or each time is different. Also please put the code you're using to getItem from storage

Comment: check the issues in react-native github issue
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18372
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14101

apparently it is a very "popular issue" happening not even solved in version 0.57. 

This issue hits to certain devices like android 7.0 and android 8.0.

Comment: I am seeing this issue on Google Pixel 3 XL, the first query to Async Storage is super long, subsequent requests are relatively short. Only occurs on Android

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is is still having this issue with RN >= 0.60 & Async-Storage >= 1.6.1, I solved the issue by setting a dedicated thread executor in android as outlined here: https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage/blob/LEGACY/docs/advanced/DedicatedExecutor.md